# Get index range of the repetitive elements in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

Suppose I have a list `a = [-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1]` in python what i want is if there is any built in function in python in which we pass a list and it will return which element are present at what what index ranges for example

```
>>> index_range(a)
{-1 :'0-2,9-11', 1:'3-5,12-14', 2:'6-8'}
```

I have tried to use `Counter` function from `collection.Counter` library but it only outputs the count of the element.

If there is not any built in function can you please guide me how can i achieve this in my own function not the whole code just a guideline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your custom function using [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to get the range of numbers in the form of list as:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict


def index_range(my_list):
    my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for i, j in groupby(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda x: x[1]):
        index_range, numlist = list(zip(*j))
        my_dict[numlist[0]].append((index_range[0], index_range[-1]))
    return my_dict
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> index_range([-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1])
{1: [(3, 5), (12, 14)], 2: [(6, 8)], -1: [(0, 2), (9, 11)]}
```

---

In order **to get the values as string in your dict**, you may either modify the above function, or use the return value of the function in *dictionary comprehension* as:

```
>>> result_dict = index_range([-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1])

>>> {k: ','.join('{}:{}'.format(*i) for i in v)for k, v in result_dict.items()}
{1: '3:5,12:14', 2: '6:8', -1: '0:2,9:11'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` that uses list items as keys and their indexes as values:

```
>>> lst = [-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1]
>>> indexes = {}
>>> for index, item in enumerate(lst):
...    indexes.setdefault(value, []).append(index)
>>> indexes
{1: [3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14], 2: [6, 7, 8], -1: [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11]}
```

You could then merge the index lists into ranges if that's what you need. I can help you with that too if necessary.